# What are folders Gift, MBSTGO & MBSTPH?

Tags: storage, motorola-moto-g

Moto G, Android 4.4.4

What are folders MBSTGO & MBSTPH?

Which app creates them? Can I safely delete them?

Comment: Where are they?

Comment: Related discussion on XDA: http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/folders-gift-myrecord-mbstgo-mbstph-t2918141

Answer (score 0):

If they don't have anything in them, then it should be fine to delete because they'll just be auto generated again when the app needs it.

Answer (score -1):

MBSTPH is folder for low level protected mode run and shut. Contents png test mark inmages. Don't delete!

Comment: Could you provide any references to backup this answer?

Comment: and "accroos promote"  & "my records" folders?